# How to extract the value from a nested dictionary within a nested list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

The following is my code snippet. I am trying to extract the value of 'string' and 'score' from a nested dictionary within a nested list . How do I accomplish this?

Expected output would be 'Object element' and '1.0'

```
[{'Form': [{'string': 'object element', 'score': 1.0,}],
  'types': ['http://google.com'],
'threshold':34}]
```

Comment: What have you tried? Do you want this done in a loop, or simply extract the value of the first(only) `'string'` and `'score'` values? Also, I think the final braces might be a bit mixed up?

Comment: I tried to flatten the list first through reduce function and then tried to unpack the value via list indexing, but no luck.. Yes, I want this to be done in a loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work

```
data = [{'Form': [{'string': 'object element', 'score': 1.0,}], 'types': ['http://google.com'], 'threshold':34},{'Form': [{'string': 'data store', 'score': 0.9,}], 'types': ['http://google.com'], 'threshold':23}]

for d in data:
    print(d['Form'][0]['string'])
    print(d['Form'][0]['score'])
```

Comment: Thanks @Nithin. Actually I missed stating my problem clearly. I would ideally like the solution in loop cos my code  is of below format  `[{'Form': [{'string': 'object element', 'score': 1.0,}],
  'types': ['http://google.com'],
'threshold':34},{'Form': [{'string': 'data store', 'score': 0.9,}],
  'types': ['http://google.com'],
'threshold':23}]`

Comment: Thanks a ton @Nithin. This is exactly what I was looking for.